# Haskell - could not find module 'Test.QuickCheck'

Tags: haskell, module, quickcheck, cabal-install

I'm getting an error that says the module doesn't exist when I try to runhaskell. It's odd because I try to install it first and says its up to date. Any idea how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: You probably need to add a dependency in your cabal file.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/nNaeODy.png I added this to my cabal file and ran cabal configure, cabal build, and cabal install. I got this error at cabal install: https://i.imgur.com/6zATtvu.png

Comment: runhaskell calls GHC which doesn't expose modules by default.  Why are you using runhaskell if you have a cabal file?  Can you not `cabal run`?

Comment: The license error just says you need a license file  `touch LICENSE` to make a blank one.  I dislike this cabal behavior but am sure there is a long argument on the issue tracker.

Comment: How can I make ghc expose modules? I'd rather use runhaskell

Comment: You can use the `-package` flag such as `runhaskell -package QuickCheck Ex1.hs`.

Comment: Hm, another error. https://i.imgur.com/l6kasN1.png Any idea how to fix this one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try creating the [package environment](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-environments) in the *local* directory that holds your project, like this:

```
c:\Users\...\ex1haskell> cabal install --lib --package-env . QuickCheck
```

This should create a file of the form `.ghc.environment.xxx` in `ex1haskell`, which hopefully should be picked up by `runhaskell`/`ghci`/`ghc` invocations.

In `ghci` sessions, a sign that the environment is being picked up is the following message while starting:

> Loaded package environment from ...

When the `--package-env` location is not given explicitly, a default location is used. [According to the docs](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-commands.html#cabal-v2-install):

> By default, it is writing to the global environment in
> ~/.ghc/$ARCH-$OS-$GHCVER/environments/default. v2-install provides the
> --package-env flag to control which of these environments is modified.

But it seems that `runhaskell` is having problems to find the environment file in that default location.

**Note**. When creating a package environment, it's possible to specify multiple packages simultaneously, like this:

```
cabal install --lib --package-env . QuickCheck random aeson transformers
```

Also, package environments are just text files, so local environments can be deleted and recreated at will. The actual package binaries reside elsewhere and can potentially be reused by `cabal`.

Comment: The problem with not finding the default global environment on Windows is caused by a bug: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/19286

Comment: This solution helped a lot !.  I am on ubuntu, and was looking to use the "text" package. Created the local environment as above using the "--package-env" command,  Note: a small adjustment I made . in ghci "import Text.CSV" asked me to ":set -package csv" to expose the member of the text package. After that "import Text.CSV" worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

**A Common Environment**

It is hard to debug if/when the actual tooling differs so let's first get a unified setup.  I'll use docker to get GHC 8 and Cabal 3.x:

```
docker run --rm -it haskell bash
```

Understand that this isn't arbitrary or even preemptive.  What you have shown - `cabal install --lib ...` and `runhaskell ...` does work for sane tool installations.  You might have a bad installation or an old version of a tool that has different behavior.

**Running a single file with runhaskell**

Now we need a project:

```
root@8a934c302dba:/# mkdir Ex1
root@8a934c302dba:/# cd Ex1
root@8a934c302dba:/Ex1# cat <<EOF >Main.hs
> import Test.QuickCheck
>
> main :: IO ()
> main = print =<< (generate arbitrary :: IO Int)
> EOF
```

And test failure:

```
root@8a934c302dba:/Ex1# runhaskell Main.hs

Main.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not find module `Test.QuickCheck'
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Test.QuickCheck
```

And install the library:

```
root@8a934c302dba:/Ex1# cabal update && cabal install --lib QuickCheck
```

And successful run:

```
root@8a934c302dba:/Ex1# runhaskell Main.hs
15
```

So my comment above was wrong - we don't need to explicitly list the package as it is already exposed after installation.

Comment: I tried doing cabal update, then cabal install, then runhaskell as I don't think I've tried that sequence of steps yet, but still doesn't work. I'll try creating a new working directory like you.

Comment: Doesn't work for me - import QuickCheck fails.; cabal info QuickCheck says "not installed". Have to use v1-install, then it works.

Comment: I was able to execute exactly my above sequence successfully.   Are you sure you ran the "And install the library" part as shown? Can you paste-bin your full set of steps?