# Haskell timeit Module - SystemTimeIT not found

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

This must be very simple; but why this error:

```
PS C:\Users\guthrie\Desktop> cabal install --lib timeit
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
PS C:\Users\guthrie\Desktop> ghci
GHCi, version 8.10.2: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :m System.TimeIt

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module `System.TimeIt'
    Perhaps you meant System.Timeout (from base-4.14.1.0)
Prelude>
Leaving GHCi.
```

Hackage shows System.TimeIt as being defined in timeit-2.0, which is what cabal installed.

```
PS C:\Users\guthrie\Desktop> cabal install timeit
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-8.10.2 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - timeit-2.0 (lib) (requires download & build)
Downloading  timeit-2.0
Downloaded   timeit-2.0
Starting     timeit-2.0 (lib)
Building     timeit-2.0 (lib)
Installing   timeit-2.0 (lib)
Completed    timeit-2.0 (lib)
```

Checking again:

```
PS C:\Users\guthrie\Desktop> cabal install --lib timeit
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
```

But trying to check on it from cabal info::

```
PS C:\Users\guthrie\Desktop> cabal info timeit
* timeit           (library)
    Synopsis:      Time monadic computations with an IO base.
    Versions available: 0.9.0.0, 1.0.0.0, 2.0
    Versions installed: [ Not installed ]
    Homepage:      https://github.com/merijn/timeit
    Bug reports:   https://github.com/merijn/timeit/issues
    Description:   A simple wrapper to show the used CPU time of monadic
                   computation with an IO base.
    Category:      System
    License:       BSD3
    Author:        Lennart Augustsson
    Maintainer:    Merijn Verstraaten <merijn@inconsistent.nl>, Lennart Augustsson
    Source repo:   ssh://github.com:merijn/timeit.git
    Dependencies:  base >=3 && <5, transformers >=0.2 && <0.6
    Cached:        Yes
    Modules:
        System.TimeIt
```

So it reports: "Not installed".
Same problem with criterion (Criterion.Main).

I see a note from 2/2020; that if a package is installed without the --lib option,

> *It does add the library to the package db in this case but does not
> add it to the default environment*.
> (*https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6262#issuecomment-589843722)

So I repeated the install with this option, no effect - just reported "Up to date".

That same link gave a solution (work-around?) to use instead cabal v1-install, which does work. But what would be the recommended *simple* solution to be able just to use ghci for testing small codes? Forced migration to stack, with local sandboxed and copies of everything for every small test?

Since I am only doing very simple short tests of examples, I was not creating a sandbox for each, and do not have a .cabal file, are those now necessary?!

(cabal 3.2.0.o, ghc 8.10.2, Windows 10)

Comment: Use a local environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837574/haskell-could-not-find-module-test-quickcheck/63841684#63841684

Comment: Yes, I've seen that - but the question was if using the -lib option would (should) work, and else it is accurate that the prior (cabal install, ghci) usage is just now gone. That note says to create a separate directory and environment for every .hs file, not so convenient when I have a folder with 80-90 simple one file.hs samples. An additional comment there says that using the --lib on cabal install, should work with a default global repository, which it didn't for me. I'll retest this.

Comment: The default global repository not working might be a bug. In theory it should work. You don't need an environment for each hs file, a single environment in the folder with the dependencies for all the files will be enough. You can also specify the location of the environment file with the GHC_ENVIRONMENT environment variable https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#envvar-GHC_ENVIRONMENT

Comment: Yes - thanks. But that also couples the code.hs files to a particular directory. I don't have the GHC_ENVIRONMENT variable set, will see if pointing it to a global repository helps. But as you notes, the legacy "cabal install --lib; ghc" should work.

Comment: I have reproduced the problem with the default environment on Windows and opened a GHC issue: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/19286

Comment: Thank you! that is the right way to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend that you don't try to use `ghc` and `ghci` directly but instead use `cabal`. If you want to quickly play around with `timeit` in the REPL then use

```
cabal v2-repl --build-depends timeit
```

If you want to do anything more complicated then create a (perhaps temporary) project and add `timeit` as a dependency:

```
$ mkdir my-temporary-package
$ cd my-temporary-package
$ cabal init
```

Edit `my-temporary-package.cabal` to change

```
build-depends:       base >=... && <...
```

to

```
build-depends:       base, timeit
```

(The constraints on base are going to cause you more harm than good for a quick exploratory project. You can add them back later if it becomes necessary.)  Then

```
$ cabal v2-repl
```

will get you a REPL with `timeit` available.