# I have installed cassava-0.5.2.0, but the compiler is still complaining

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to get Cassava up and running. I have successfully install cassava-0.5.2.0, but when I try to compile

```
import Data.Csv
import qualified Data.Vector as V

x = 3
```

compiler is spitting it with the error message
`Could not find module ‘Data.Csv’`. Why could this be?

Comment: If you are using `ghc` or `ghci` directly, try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63841684/1364288 if you are creating a Cabal package, add cassava to the `build-depends:` section of the Cabal file.