# What is the difference between install, v1-install, v2-install and new-install?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

The commands `install`, `v1-install`, `v2-install` and `new-install` are simply described to "Install packages" when running `man cabal`. Are they different from one another? Which is the preferred option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For [modern](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/nix-local-build-overview.html) versions of cabal-install, [`install`, `new-install` and `v2-install`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-commands.html#cabal-v2-install) are the same. `v1-install` and the other `v1-` commands are obsolete and should not be used anymore.

Notice that, when developing a cabal package, *the `install` command is largely unnecessary*. Running [`cabal build`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-commands.html#cabal-v2-build) and [`cabal repl`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-commands.html#cabal-v2-repl) will automatically install the required dependencies (listed in the [`build-depends:`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html#pkg-field-build-depends) section of the [cabal file](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/file-format-changelog.html)).

`cabal install` is still useful in cases like the following:

- Installing an executable from a package. Like the `warp` executable from the package [wai-app-static](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-app-static). In those cases, the options `--overwrite-policy`,  `--install-method` and  `--installdir` are useful.
- Creating a local [package environment](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-environments) in some folder, so that "bare" invocations of `ghc` and `ghci` see some desired set of libraries. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63841684/1364288). In those cases, the options `--lib` and `--package-env` are useful.

Comment: The fact that completely different sets of options are relevant for different cases suggests that the command should be split into two: one for installing executables, and another for creating package environments.