# How to install package for Haskell with stack and cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I'm attempting to install one small Haskell package.

I set up a project using `stack`:

```
stack new my-project simple
```

This worked out fine. I'm able to build and run the code.

But then I stumbled into needing to use some other library. Searching the internet, I found that I should use `cabal` to do that. First installed it:

```
brew install cabal-install
```

Then updated it:

```
cabal update
```

Then tried to install a library with it:

```
cabal install --lib split
```

This resulted in:

```
Warning: Unknown/unsupported 'ghc' version detected (Cabal 3.10.1.0 supports
'ghc' version < 9.8): /usr/local/bin/ghc is version 9.8.1
Warning: Unknown/unsupported 'ghc' version detected (Cabal 3.10.1.0 supports
'ghc' version < 9.8): /usr/local/bin/ghc is version 9.8.1
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-9.8.1 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - split-0.2.4 (lib) (requires download & build)
Downloading  split-0.2.4
Downloaded   split-0.2.4
Starting     split-0.2.4 (lib)
Building     split-0.2.4 (lib)

Failed to build split-0.2.4.
Build log ( /Users/nene/.cache/cabal/logs/ghc-9.8.1/splt-0.2.4-d1ef7190.log ):
Configuring library for split-0.2.4..
Preprocessing library for split-0.2.4..
Building library for split-0.2.4..
[1 of 2] Compiling Data.List.Split.Internals ( src/Data/List/Split/Internals.hs, dist/build/Data/List/Split/Internals.o, dist/build/Data/List/Split/Internals.dyn_o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Data.List.Split  ( src/Data/List/Split.hs, dist/build/Data/List/Split.o, dist/build/Data/List/Split.dyn_o )
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/lib'
ld: unknown option: -no_fixup_chains
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`clang' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
Error: cabal: Failed to build split-0.2.4. See the build log above for
details.
```

There seems to be a conflict with cabal version (3.10.1.0) and GHC version (9.8.1). Not sure how to solve it.

Additionally I have a `my-project.cabal` file that `stack` created. Inside it I see:

```
cabal-version:       2.2
```

If my mental model is correct, then `stack` uses its own separate GHC installation and (possibly) also its own Cabal installation. But I have no idea how to access these.

I tried creating `package.yaml` file (as suggested by Silvio Mayolo) with the following contents:

```yaml
dependencies:
- split
```

But this seems to have no effect. The build simply complains that it's unable to find `Data.List.Split` module (which the `split` library should provide).

**PS:** For now I have simply implemented the little function I wanted to import by myself. But it would be nice to figure out how to install some Haskell libraries.

Comment: Stack manages a curated build, sort of like a virtual environment for your project, so if you're using Stack then you should use Stack to manage dependencies as well. `stack new` should've created a file called `package.yaml`, and your dependencies should go in the `dependencies:` section of that file. Then Stack will auto-download those dependencies.

Comment: Emm... `Warning: /stack.yaml: Unrecognized field in ProjectAndConfigMonoid: dependencies`

Comment: Sorry... added it to the wrong file. Looks like `stack` did not create a `package.yaml` file for me. I only see `stack.yaml` and `stack.yaml.lock`

Comment: Possibly I'm also using an old version of stack: 2.13.1.

Comment: Hmm... no. Looks like I'm on the latest version of stack.

Comment: Looks like the `package.yaml` file was not created because I used the `simple` template when calling `stack new`. Is there some way to install dependencies into this simple setup? I really just wanted to keep the amount of boilerplate to the minimum as I just wanted to write a very small toy-program, but looks like I've digged some hole for myself.

Comment: If your goal is a toy program, then I'd cut out Stack. You can write a small toy (especially if it's just one file) by managing dependencies yourself with Cabal and just not using Stack at all. There's going to be a certain amount of unavoidable overhead with Stack, simply because it's designed for larger projects.

Comment: Yeah... but then I'm back to the problem that the version of Cabal I have doesn't support the version of GHC I have.

Comment: At least with stack I'm now able to install dependencies. Though I had to ditch the use of the `simple` template.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66535628/what-is-the-difference-between-install-v1-install-v2-install-and-new-install/66535928#66535928

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a dependency to a project created with the simple template, you need to add it to the `build-depends` field in the `.cabal` file created by the template - in your case `my-project.cabal`.

After that, your cabal file should look like this:

```
cabal-version:       2.2

name:                my-project
version:             0.1.0.0
-- synopsis:
-- description:
homepage:            https://github.com/githubuser/my-project#readme
license:             BSD-3-Clause
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Author name here
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           2023 Author name here
category:            Web
build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files:  README.md
                     CHANGELOG.md

executable my-project
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5, split
  ghc-options:         -Wall
                       -Wcompat
                       -Widentities
                       -Wincomplete-record-updates
                       -Wincomplete-uni-patterns
                       -Wmissing-export-lists
                       -Wmissing-home-modules
                       -Wpartial-fields
                       -Wredundant-constraints
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to try out something quickly then `cabal run my-script.hs`, with `my-script.hs` being

```hs
{- cabal:
build-depends: base, split
-}
import Data.List.Split
main = print $ splitOn "x" "axbxc"
```

is the easiest (and single file) solution.

Some more notes:

- use only cabal if you can, it's the core build and packaging tool for haskell
- stack and stackage are (1) a project management tool (where you have more cabal libraries than one), and (2) a curated package list. "curated" as in "all these packages build together without errors", it's subset of the entire [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/), the place cabal goes to find all the packages. *Stack depends on cabal*, and adds its extra functionality on top.
- `package.yaml` is a source for the yaml-based .cabal file generator [hpack](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hpack). (If you run `hpack` in the same folder where `package.yaml` is, it will create a `my-package.cabal` from it.) *Stack also depends on hpack* and runs it by default if it finds `package.yaml` files within your project
- cabal has over the years gotten better at both project management and in .cabal file syntax (there is also the `cabal.project` file which enables multi-package projects), so one might get by with just using that

Comment: Unfortunately running `cabal` directly results in a linker error: `ld: unknown option: -no_fixup_chain` followed by `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Hmm, maybe reinstalling cabal (from a different source) helps? Is that on an M series Apple machine?

Comment: Nope. An older MacBook. Probably need to install cabal and/or ghc differently. As I wrote in the original question there seems to be a mismatch between my cabal and ghc installations. But for now I don't really care enough to dig into this. I'm fine running it all through stack - at least it ensures the correct combo of ghc and cabal.