# How to read all file names from directory?

Tags: haskell

How do I read all file names from a directory in Haskell?

I tried to use the `getDirectoryContents` function and put:

```
import System.Directory (doesDirectoryExist, getDirectoryContents)
```

but it gave an error on the import:

```
Could not load module ‘System.Directory’
It is a member of the hidden package ‘directory-1.3.6.0’.
You can run ‘:set -package directory’ to expose it.
```

Where should I run `:set -package directory`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63841684/1364288

Answer (score 2):

That error looks like a ghci error. If so, then you can simply enter the `:set` command directly into ghci.

For ghc itself, you may look into `ghc-pkg` for the very low-level control or `cabal` for a more sensible user experience. With the latter, you would list `directory` in the `build-depends` field of the appropriate `library` or `executable` stanze in your `whatever.cabal` file, then use `cabal repl` to interact with ghci instead of using `ghci` directly. (There are more gentle, detailed introductions to this tool elsewhere -- just have a Google.)